# Running google app script from another app script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to run a google app script from a different app script?

im just getting into google app scripts and i couldnt find anything on the internet

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are looking for libraries functionality in Google App Script. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

You can save a version of the script that you have the functions in it, and import the functions on to a second script file through menu>resources>libraries. You need to use script id for importing libraries, which you can find from menu>File>Project properties>Script ID

You can then execute the function using the script file name as the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Apps Script API, you may find this helpful [Executing Functions using the Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute)

"The Apps Script API provides a scripts.run method that remotely executes a specified Apps Script function"

Answer (score 0):

You can call google app script form javascript or web page.
You have to implement doGet(or post) and publish your google app script.

I found good [example](https://ctrlq.org/code/20197-jquery-ajax-call-google-script).

Cheers.